# Passing parameters to a rails 3 form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way i can pass a value to a form from another page?

In Classic ASP i Would possibly do it via a querystring like - http://www.yoursite.com?id=123

then the form value would be - `<%=Request.QueryString("id")%>`

I basically need to pass an id from a button to a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [params](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) hash. You could do something like:

```
<%= params[:id] %>
```